# The weight of the extended ternary Golay code

Tags: coding-theory

I need to show that the extended ternary Golay code with parameters $[12,6]$ is a self dual code and has minimum weight $6$ so i will obtain a $[12,6,6]$-code.
I showed the self duality but how can I show that the minimum weight is $6$?

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Show that the code has no words of weight three. Also use the fact that if
$\vec{c}=(c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_{12})$ is a codeword, then, by self-duality, its weight
$$
w=\vec{c}\cdot\vec{c}\equiv0\pmod3.
$$
The first equality follows from the fact $c_i^2=1$ for all non-zero values of $c_i$.

The most convenient way of excluding the possibility of weight three words may be to use the description of the (unextended) ternary Golay code as a QR-code (=quadratic residue code), and the general results on the minimum distance of QR-codes.

Comment: in H matrix if we show no 5 columns are linearly dependent,does that imply the minimum weight is 6 jyrki lahtonen?

Comment: Yes it does. Actually it suffices to show that no three columns are linearly independent, because self-duality implies (as above) that the weight of a codeword is a multiple of three, so you only need to rule out the possibility of the minimum distance being three. But there are ${12\choose 3}=220$ combinations of three columns. Therefore I would also consider resorting to the theory of QR-codes as a labor saving device.

Comment: can you give more details?how can i use your idea?can you give an example if possible?

Comment: @juliet: How to best exclude the possibility of weight three words depends on how much you have covered in your course. If you haven't done QR-codes, then my previous comment is probably all Greek to you. Did you understand why self-duality implies that there cannot be words of weights 1,2,4 or 5?