# Ternary Golay codes and correction probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics, coding-theory

We define the probability of a given linear binary code C [n,k] as:

$$P_{corr}(C)=\sum_{i=0}^n\alpha_i(p)^i(1-p)^{n-i}$$

Where $\alpha_i$ is the number of coset leaders of weight $i$.

I am asked to show that, for the ternary Golay codes:

> $$P_{corr}(G_{11})=P_{corr}(G_{12})$$

First of all, both codes are ternary so I believe we have to replace $p$ with $p/2$ (as the akphabet has 3 letters) Since $G_{11}$ is a perfect code, I can tell right away that:
$\alpha_0=1, \alpha_1=22, \alpha_2=220$.
$G_{12}$ has minimum distance from a given vector at 3, and thus we have:
$\alpha_0=1, \alpha_1=24, \alpha_2=264, \alpha_3=440$ Where the last was computed as to complete the right number of coset leaders.

Putting this values into theformula above, however, I get:

$$P_{corr}(G_{11})=(1-p/2)^9(199/4*p^2+10p+1)$$
$$P_{corr}(G_{12})=(1-p/2)^9(1+p/2)(199/4*p^2+10p+1)$$

And that means they are obviously not equal. I went through my algebra again and again, and also double-checked with wolframalpha. My coset computation seems to be correct. Am I mistaken regarding the $p/2$ (not that it will help), or is it someplace else? Where am I mistaken?

Comment: What is your definition of the extended ternary Golay code? If the definition of the extension symbol is $$C_{12} = - \sum_{i=1}^{11} C_i,$$ then it is not necessarily the case that a codeword of odd Hamming weight in the original code is mapped to a codeword of even Hamming weight in the extended code.

Comment: It is the [12,6,6] linear code, so that puncturing it leads to the [11,6,5] ternary golay code, $G_{11}$

Comment: The weights of the extended ternary Golay code are [multiples of three](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/390161/11619), [because it is self-dual](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/837122/11619).

Comment: Oh, now I see! You correctly used powers of $p/2$ multiplied by $\alpha_i$:s, because the error in a ternary symbol can take two distinct values, and in a symmetric channel they are equally likely. But that $1-p$ should stay, because it is the probability of no error in that symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got (or rather, Mathematica got) the same polynomial for both codes. 
I also got the same numbers of coset leaders of various weight that you did. For comparison:

$$
\begin{aligned}
P(G_{11},p)&=(1-p)^{11}+22(\frac p2)(1-p)^{10}+220(\frac p2)^2(1-p)^9\\
&=1 - 165 p^3 + 990 p^4 - 2772 p^5 + 4620 p^6 - 4950 p^7 + 3465 p^8 - 
 1540 p^9 + 396 p^{10} - 45 p^{11}
\end{aligned}
$$
and
$$
\begin{aligned}
P(G_{12},p)&=(1-p)^{12}+24(\frac p2)(1-p)^{11}+264(\frac p2)^2(1-p)^{10}+440(\frac p2)^3(1-p)^9\\
&=1 - 165 p^3 + 990 p^4 - 2772 p^5 + 4620 p^6 - 4950 p^7 + 3465 p^8 - 
 1540 p^9 + 396 p^{10} - 45 p^{11}.
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Thank you! The issue clearly was with the (1-p). Is there a general rule of thumb as to the probability of error in a symmetric channel over $GF(q)$? I assume probability of error is $p/(q-1)$ and of no error $1-p$?

Comment: Just redo the derivation of that formula for $P_{corr}(C)$ in qSC. I'm not sure what happens, but an educated guess would be that $1-p$ always stays the same, and $p/2$ becomes $p/(q-1)$. Frankly, I think trying to memorize such things is pointless. Memorize/understand what those terms represent, and everything else comes naturally.